# How to sort a List<int[]> in GWT? fails with custom Comparator

Tags: java, gwt

I have a List in GWT and I wish to sort it but GWT complains at runtime that it cannot be done.

```
    List<int[]> tuples = new LinkedList<int[]>();
    tuples.sort(new TupleComparator());

    class TupleComparator implements Comparator<int[]> {

        @Override
        public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
            int i = 0;
            int l = o1.length;
            while (i < l && o1[i] == o2[i]) {
                i++;
            }
            return (i == l ? 0 : o1[i] - o2[i]);
        }
    }

    [ERROR] [testgwtlistofint] - Line 116: The method sort(TupleComparator) 
    is undefined for the type List<int[]>
```

Comment: Instead of Comparator<int[]> it must be Comparator<int>. When sorting an Array, you compare the array elements, not the array itself.

Comment: @quant That is not correct. The list contains `int[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are obviously calling the method `sort()` as defined in the `List` interface. Take a look at the javadocs for Java7/Java8:

- [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

`List.sort()` was added in Java 8. My guess is you are trying to run the code with Java 7 or below.

If you get a run time error, the code is probably compiled with Java 8, but executed with Java 7 or below. Your code does not compile with Java 7.

For sorting in Java 7, use `Collections.sort(tuples, new TupleComparator());`.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to convert Java 8 code to work in Java 7 in GWT.

Comment: @Phil Then the solution for you is to use `Collections.sort(tuples, new TupleComparator());`.